# Why is the Angular canActivate function guard executed twice when navigating routes

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 5 and have a couple of routes defined. When I navigate routes and put a breakpoint on the canActivate function guard, I see it is executed twice.

I'm asking this because I have to call an external service on each canActivate call, and executing the same service uselessly multiple times causes unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Just happened to me, and the problem was this snippet in my `AuthGuard`:

```
setActiveWebsite(website: string): void {
    this._website.next(website);
    this.router.navigate([]);  <-- This line here
}
```

It executed twice because it sets a value, redirects, and then skipped auth because it resolved to `true` immediately.

---

Are you, maybe, using `route.navigate` or a redirect in one of your `guards` or `resolvers`?

Comment: i understand using route.navigate inside guards or resolver is wrong. what is the alternative? (assuming i want to redirect to a different route)

Comment: @omer You are right, you should not call navigate inside a guard; instead you should return a `UrlTree` (optionally wrapped in an `Observable` or a `Promise`) with the desired redirect.

Answer (score 2):

It is ran several times because the router has several events to handle. You could test if this is the last event with something like this.

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    // Last event, do your thing
  }
});
```

Comment: The canActivate route is called twice and apparently it happens when { useHash: true } is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348132/angular-2-canactivate-is-called-twice

Answer (score 1):

It is the not the `canActivate` being executed multiple times, but it is the event that you have subscribed to. In your case it would be the `router` event.

You can watch for only the last event which is `NavigationEnd` as explained in the other answer by @trichetriche.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 7.1 solves this problem with the *router.parseUrl()* method, which takes the path name (as set in the routing module) as an argument.

So instead of `router.navigate(['__'])` or `router.navigateByUrl('__')`, which by the way should followed by a [false return](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) if used as a redirect, you would do the elegant `return router.parseUrl('____')`.

I exhausted so many variations of the previous methods that I now plan my days around a calendar composed strictly of angular guard logic.

In removing the need for me to travel home every time I wanted check that calendar, this new parseUrl() upgrade has substantially improved my life.

Hat tip to [Nate Lapinski and the fantastic Angular In Depth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/new-in-angular-v7-1-updates-to-the-router-fd67d526ad05).